# Syntax error setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm going through a book of java exercises and have gotten stuck on this syntax error. I've searched onSetClickListener syntax errors and don't think I'm duplicating questions. Eclipse says 'Syntax error on token "setOnClickListener", Identifier expected after this token'. Thanks for your help!

```
package fifth.example.eventhandling;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);  <<ERROR HERE

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textmessage);
        text.setText("BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED. EVENT PROCESSED.");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

One issue is that the Button related code you have here in the code should be inside `onCreate()` and after `setContentView...`

```
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);  <<ERROR HERE

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

should be:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button button; //declare button hear 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);  <<ERROR HERE

    }
}
```

Comment: @viatierra : this not right way to ask question after getting answer delete it . kindly accept an answer if you get help here friend

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are trying initialize button before setting layout for Activity . move button initialization inside onCreate of Activity after  `setContentView`  as :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button button ; //<<< declare  button here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  //<<< initilze here
       button.setOnClickListener(this);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(this);  <<ERROR HERE
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textmessage);
    text.setText("BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED. EVENT PROCESSED.");

}
```